# Entity Framework Core 5 doesn't work in Unity3D 2022 even though .NET Standard 2.1 is supported

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm using 2022.3.4f1 of the Unity game engine, [which is supposed to support NET Standard 2.1](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.3/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html). However when I try to install the Nuget package for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v5.0.17, which [targets NET Standard 2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/5.0.17), I get the following error:

```bash
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.17' with respect to project 'Assembly-CSharp', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1'
Gathering dependency information took 2.79 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.17' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the existing packages.config file. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 3.1.32 constraint: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.1.32)'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.17'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.17'
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.17' from 'nuget.org'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.17' does not exist in project 'Assembly-CSharp'
Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.17' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\Atlinx\Documents\Unity\Unity Projects\QuestDispatch\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 1.45 sec
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.17'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 5.0.17
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
Time Elapsed: 00:00:04.7149747
```

I feel like it's caused by the csproj having the following line:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

From my research, NET Framework versions (v4.6, v4.7 ...) all the way up to the last version (v4.8) target only NET Standard 2.0. However, I'm not sure how I can change it to use NET Standard 2.1 instead.

Comment: You can't use EF Core 5+ in a .NET Framework or .NET Standard 2.0 application. No .NET Framework version targets .NET Standard 2.1. Only .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5+ work with it.

Comment: Is Unity 2022 support for NET Standard 2.1 a lie then?

Comment: You aren't targeting that at all. Did your project target the wrong SDK perhaps?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/overview-of-dot-net-in-unity.html Unity does **not "use"** `.NET Framework` nor `.NET Standard 2.1` ... it uses something that **supports** most of the API these provide .. it has some restrictions though

Comment: .NET Standard is an API specification, not a runtime or executable. Various runtimes and versions support different versions of those APIs. In the end, your *executable* platform should support the API specification you chose. If you create a .NET Standard 2.1 plugin, you can't use it in a .NET *Framework* executable

Comment: This https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html would have been the more specific link ;)

Comment: I think main issue regarding `EntityFramework` is that it does runtime code generation which Unity doesn't support at all

Comment: Ah, would using EntityFramework/EntityFrameworkCore in Unity be an impossible task?

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with others in the comments, it seems like Unity uses .NET Framework for its C# projects, so it can only use .NET Standard 2.0 libraries.

I also tried using EntityFrameworkCore 3.x, which targets .NET Standard 2.0, however, it still caused problems since Unity began to complain about missing assembly references.

Ultimately, I followed [Kurt-Dekker's advice on the Unity Forms](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-use-entity-framework-core-with-unity.1339796/) to use a Unity-built solution instead. I ended up finding the [UnitySQLiteAsync](https://github.com/kdw9502/UnitySQLiteAsync) package, which served my needs.